# How to clear `Summary` metric value in Python Prometheus client

Tags: prometheus, prometheus-python-client

I'm using Prometheus Python client [here](https://github.com/prometheus/client_python). How do you clear a `Summary` metric without any labels? Example

```py
metric = Summary("test_summary", "")
metric.observe(10)
# Do something
metric.clear()
```

The last line throws the following error:

```
self = prometheus_client.metrics.Summary(test_metric)

    def clear(self) -> None:
        """Remove all labelsets from the metric"""
>       with self._lock:
E       AttributeError: 'Summary' object has no attribute '_lock'

../../anaconda3/envs/testenv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/prometheus_client/metrics.py:204: AttributeError
```